# Not able to use iText PdfDiv Position Absolute

Tags: java, pdf, itext

[image]I am using iText-5.5.2 in java to generate pdf files. I have one PdfDiv inside of another PdfDiv and will like to set the position on Div2 to absolute to manage the position of Div2. Position = absolute just doesn't work, when I set it to absolute, div2 just show at it's static location. But postion = relative and static works. 
Image shows the result I always get, I can get the right TOP to show. Is there a bug in itext when PdfDiv Position = Absolute or I made a mistake?

```
    PdfDiv laDivPrint = new PdfDiv();
    laDivPrint.setPosition(PdfDiv.PositionType.RELATIVE);
    laDivPrint.setWidth(101);
    laDivPrint.setHeight(100);

    PdfDiv laDivText = new PdfDiv();
    laDivText.setPosition(PositionType.ABSOLUTE);

    laDivText.setWidth((float) 100);        
    laDivText.setHeight((float) 10);
    laDivText.setTop((float) 20);
    laDivText.setLeft((float) 0);
    Chunk laChunk = new Chunk("Adam Song");
    laDivText.addElement(laChunk);

    laDivPrint.addElement(laDivText); 

    PdfDiv laDivText2 = new PdfDiv();
    laDivText2.setPosition(PositionType.ABSOLUTE);

    laDivText2.setWidth((float) 100);       
    laDivText2.setHeight((float) 10);
    laDivText2.setTop((float) 50);
    laDivText2.setLeft((float) 0);
    Chunk laChunk2 = new Chunk("My Company");
    laDivText2.addElement(laChunk2);

    laDivPrint.addElement(laDivText2);
```

Comment: Please post a sample that includes both `PdfDivs`. It would also help if you drew a simple picture (mspaint is fine) that shows what you except and what you actually get.

Comment: Just updated my question.

Comment: I downloaded the latest source code 5.5.2. In com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDiv, I just don't see there is any code that handles PdfDiv.Position = ABSOLUTE. I see code that handles PdfDiv.Position = RELATIVE, but not for ABSOLUTE, STATIC or FIX.

Comment: Hope iText can start to support PdfDiv.Position = Absolute soon.

Comment: I've been digging around the source and I can't really find too much usage of `PdfDiv` in general. However, it feels like something that is intended to give an "HTML feel" to a PDF, and possibly just a stub for something in XMLWorker to use. Regardless, I would recommend avoiding it. The PDF standard explicitly doesn't allow "floating" or "relative" positioning of things. Instead everything is absolutely positioned, **always**. From the sample you posted, I would just use `ColumnText` to achieve a fixed-width absolutely positioned object.

Comment: You mean putting 2 small ColumnText inside of 1 big ColumnText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about it more and looking at your picture I would just use a normal `PdfPTable`. If you have a web background you might have this intrinsic aversion to tables but they actually serve a purpose. If you remember back to when we used to slice things into tables on the web you'll remember that was "wrong" because things couldn't move around as easily. In a PDF, however, things aren't supposed to move around so this paradigm actually makes more sense.

*(In reality, neither "divs" or "tables" actually exist within a PDF. Anything that you do will always come down to absolutely position text, lines and images. iText just provides convenient abstractions that perform the messy calculations for you.)*

I'm a .Net guy so I work in c# but I'll try to write in Java here. I can't guarantee 100% compilation but it should be pretty close.

First, create a simple factory method for your cell. You'll want to set your shared properties here and possibly add some additional parameters if you need to.

```
private static PdfPCell CreateCell(String text, BaseColor backgroundColor) {
    PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
    c.setBackgroundColor( backgroundColor );
    c.setPadding( 20 );
    c.setBorder( 0 );

    return c;
}
```

When you create your `Document`, get rid of the margins:

```
document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Then just create your table:

```
//Create a one column table
PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(1);

//Tell it to use 100% of the page's width
t.WidthPercentage = 100;

//Create two rows with different colors
t.addCell(CreateCell("Hello", BaseColor.BLUE));
t.addCell(CreateCell("World", BaseColor.YELLOW));

//Add table to document
document.add(t);
```

This code should get you something like:

[image]